# Should the "Coverage" tab list all CSS files loaded by my page?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I use the Dev Tools coverage tab to search for unused CSS ([instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes)), will it list in its report *all* CSS files loaded on the page?  Or will it not report CSS files with 0% coverage?

In practice, I think am seeing the latter, i.e. so far I have never seen the coverage tab list a file with 100% unused bytes.  But I just want to make sure that is by design, rather than some error I need to resolve.  Also, the instructions don't make it clear that certain files will be omitted from the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Coverage analyses all css files which be apply for page. You can easy check it, just create new css file, use css styles, and import/unimport this css file and run Coverage.